# React UseState truthy/falsy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, use-state

I'm trying to initialize some state for my form component with data from the redux store. If the shippingAddress object is null, I want to set properties of formData object to empty strings. Not sure how to get it to work. Currently I am receiving an error message `saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of null`

```
const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
const { shippingAddress } = cart;
    
const [formData, setFormData] = useState(
        {
          address: shippingAddress.address,
          city: shippingAddress.city,
          country: shippingAddress.country,
          postalCode: shippingAddress.postalCode,
        } || {
          address: "",
          city: "",
          country: "",
          postalCode: "",
        }
      );
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask an actual clear, specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish this with a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to first sniff on the presence/absence of `shippingAddress`:

```js
const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
const { shippingAddress } = cart;
    
const [formData, setFormData] = useState(
  shippingAddress
    ? {
      address: shippingAddress.address,
      city: shippingAddress.city,
      country: shippingAddress.country,
      postalCode: shippingAddress.postalCode,
    }
    : {
      address: "",
      city: "",
      country: "",
      postalCode: "",
    }
);
```

Alternately, you could use the [optional chaining `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [nullish coalescing `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) operators to achieve the same affect:

```js
const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
const { shippingAddress } = cart;
    
const [formData, setFormData] = useState(
  {
    address: shippingAddress?.address ?? '',
    city: shippingAddress?.city ?? '',
    country: shippingAddress?.country ?? '',
    postalCode: shippingAddress?.postalCode ?? '',
  }
);
```

Please note this second option is a newer JS feature, so check that you have Babel or browser support as is pertinent.

Comment: Yup, the second one is less efficient, but much more simple to read :)

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks. Works as expected. Didnt know about optional chaining, thanks for heads up

Answer (score 1):

Add a safe check (Try this)

```
const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
const defaultValues = {
  address: "",
  city: "",
  country: "",
  postalCode: "",
}

const { shippingAddress = defaultValues  } = cart;
const [formData, setFormData] = useState(
  {
    address: shippingAddress.address,
    city: shippingAddress.city,
    country: shippingAddress.country,
    postalCode: shippingAddress.postalCode,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
const {
    shippingAddress
} = cart;
const [formData, setFormData] = useState(shippingAddress ? {
    address: shippingAddress.address,
    city: shippingAddress.city,
    country: shippingAddress.country,
    postalCode: shippingAddress.postalCode
} : {
    address: "",
    city: "",
    country: "",
    postalCode: "",
});
```